# Unable to deploy AI model to Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, deployment, artificial-intelligence

I am a relatively seasoned AI practitioner however, I am a complete newbie when it comes to deployment of these models. I followed an online tutorial that deployed the model locally using Docker Desktop. It created a stack of containers for frontend and backend. I installed Tensorflow in each of these containers to run the AI model (RUN pip3 install tensorflow in the Dockerfile). However, I can't deploy it on Kubernetes.
I hecked the option which allowed Docker Stacks to be sent to Kubernetes. I can see both frontend and backend images when I run `docker images`. The next step that I did was that I created a GCP project and created cluster in it. Then I pushed these images after tagging them in the specific format `gcr.io/project/name:tag` to both front end and back end. Then I deployed both and then exposed them as well as fdep (frontend) and bdep (backend). Both of them are running correctly as seen here:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

However, when I go to front end external ip and run the model, nothing happens. As if the back end is not outputting anything.
Here is what I get when I use postman to post a request on backend external IP:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Any help here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add <ip>:port in your request url?

Comment: yeah it was xx.xx.xxx.xx:8081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this multi-container docker app that was not originally developed for kubernetes, make sure specify a name when generating the service for your backend,

kubectl expose deployment bdep --port 8081 --name (name-that-the-front-end-apps-expect)

In your case, without the option --name, the service name defaults to the deployment name "bdep", but the front end apps are expecting the name "backend".

Comment: logs command is giving "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 - everytime I post a request. What specifically do you want to see from describe service because I can not post a picture in a comment.Posting a request on 30293 through postman gives "There was an error connecting"

Comment: I used kubectl describe service for both fdep and bdep. Both of their endpoints IP do not match. I have shown the screenshots in the original post.

Comment: I followed this to deploy it locally: 
https://medium.com/@dvelsner/deploying-a-simple-machine-learning-model-in-a-modern-web-application-flask-angular-docker-a657db075280
To deploy it to kubernetes I'm following:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/google-cloud-platform-i-deploy-a-docker-app-to-google-container-engine-with-kubernetes#toc-deployments-instantiating-a-container-from-the-docker-image

Comment: I've added the postman GET request to frontend. How do I try a different URL?

Comment: It says "Could not get any response" o 31547 and 30293. The servers are up and the IPs are in the picture above. You can try it out. I am getting 404 though on 8081 port

Comment: The 4200 port is for the front end which is working fine. However, run diagnosis doesn't give anything because the problem is in backend.
Can you elaborate on your last comment? I'm getting no resurces on kubectl get ingress

Comment: Curl command gives the same error. 404 Not Found. How do I check what address is the fend pod pointing at? Apologies for the basic questions. I am a complete newbie at this

Comment: That's a great idea. My linkedin is:
https://www.linkedin.com/in/muhammad-aleem-0218b5157/
My skype is:
aleem.basit1
Let's connect. Thanks!